# ASP.NET MVC (razor) using Model in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I'd like depending of a property of the model (using ASP.NET MVC 3 with razor) in a jQuery function use :

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional['xx']);
```

or

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional['yy']);
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to give some more information here.. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you could either put in in a global variable. So in your view, put something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var userRegion = '@Model.UserRegion';
</script>
```

Then in your external script you can just use the `userRegion` global variable.

Another approach could be to use the jQuery.data() method.

So in your view, attach the user's region value to any html element - body is a good one. And then you can get it in your external javascript files.

E.g. your view... probably layout page (in which case you should put it in the ViewBag)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--blah-->
    </head>
    <body data-user-region="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.UserRegion) ? "en" : ViewBag.UserRegion)">
        <!--blah-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can grab it like so:

```
var userRegion = jQuery.data(document.body, 'user-region');
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional[userRegion]);
```